# seq vs. rnf in Haskell

Tags: haskell

According to the definitions given by "Parallel and Concurrent Programming in Haskell" on page 29, the class method "return normal form" is defined as:

```
rnf a = a `seq` ()
```

Just to see if wrapping seq in another function, as the authors prescribe, really had the result of forcing 'a' to be evaluated to normal form, I tried implementing the function myself and got a result in the negative:

```
Prelude Control.DeepSeq > myrnf a = a `seq` ()
Prelude Control.DeepSeq > xs = map (+1) [1..10] :: [Int]
Prelude Control.DeepSeq > :sprint xs
xs = _
Prelude Control.DeepSeq > myrunf xs
()
Prelude Control.DeepSeq > :sprint xs
xs = _ : _
Prelude Control.DeepSeq > rnf xs
()
Prelude Control.DeepSeq > :sprint xs
xs = [2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11]
```

So have the authors made a glaring mistake, or am I missing something here?

Edit: I realised my original question contained elementary mistakes. Here is the proper form of the question.

Comment: You defined `myrunf`, but called `myrnf`.

Comment: Note that many books/articles etc. have different versions, and furthermore the same content may appear on different pages even in the same version, since multiple sources may have it typeset differently (e.g. the physical book and online version are typeset differently). I cannot find the claim you have made e.g. [here](http://community.haskell.org/~simonmar/par-tutorial.pdf) (indeed, there I only find references to 'weak head normal form' and not 'normal form', which are entirely different things).

Comment: That's just a default implementation of the method (in older versions of the library anyway). Each instance should define an appropriate implementation.

Comment: @n.m.       Ah yes my bad, that certainly clears things up... Is it usual to declare an implementation of a class method inside the class declaration itself? Because that's what the author did. Perhaps, by declaring the implementation in class, one is saying that that is the _default_ implementation, unless stated otherwise in a specific instance declaration?

Comment: @nm Yes, I think that is indeed what you're saying? :) Alright, I am happy, the world is in order again.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Perhaps, by declaring the implementation in class, one is saying that that is the default implementation, unless stated otherwise in a specific instance declaration?

Yes, that's exactly what it means. What's unusual (IMO) is that normally this default implementation is valid (i.e. does what you want) for all instances but may be overridden for efficiency or to break a cycle of default definitions (e.g. in `Eq` the default implementations are `x == y = not (x /= y)` and `x /= y = not (x == y)`, so you can override whichever is more convenient).

But in case of `rnf`, [the documentation for 1.3.0.0](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/deepseq-1.3.0.0/docs/Control-DeepSeq.html#v:rnf) says

> > The default implementation of `rnf` ... may be convenient when defining instances for data types with no unevaluated fields (e.g. enumerations).

i.e. it doesn't really work for nearly all types.

This problem has been fixed [since 1.4.0.0](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/deepseq-1.4.3.0/docs/Control-DeepSeq.html#v:rnf).